# Uploading multiple images and nested json using multipart/form-data in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization, django-rest-viewsets

I have a problem with parsing ***request.data*** in viewset. I have a model that can add multiple images depending on a product.

I want to split the ***image*** from the incoming data, send ***product data*** to ProductSerializer, and after that send ***image*** to its serializer with ***product data*** and save it.

I have two model, simply like this:

```
def Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

def ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_pics/')
```

The request I want to send to the ***Product*** (127.0.0.1:8000/products/) is simply like:

```
{
    "name": "strawberry",
    "color": {
        "name": "red"
    },
    "productimage_set": [
        {"image": "<some_encode_image_data>"}
    ]
}
```

There is nothing special in the serializer, it just extracts the tags link, so I did not write it. How do I send ***multipart/form-data*** and how can I parse it in the viewset? or what is the solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I developed a solution. Using Postman, I sent multipart/form-data containing multiple images, single and nested data.

In my model file, I added the Tags model as ManyToManyField to be an example, and also django-taggit. ***form-data*** will be like in the picture.

[image]

and `models.py`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    taggit = TaggableManager(blank=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_path/', null=True, blank=True)

class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

First things first; the first data was not parsed correctly. As a solution to this and with the help of that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload/50514022#50514022), I created this custom ***parser***:

```
class MultipartJsonParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        result = super().parse(
            stream,
            media_type=media_type,
            parser_context=parser_context
        )
        data = {}

        for key, value in result.data.items():
            if type(value) != str:
                data[key] = value
                continue
            if '{' in value or "[" in value:
                try:
                    data[key] = json.loads(value)
                except ValueError:
                    data[key] = value
            else:
                data[key] = value
        return parsers.DataAndFiles(data, result.files)
```

Now we can parse our data with this parser and Django REST built-in JSONParser. Now it's time to build our ***viewsets***.

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultipartJsonParser, JSONParser]

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(ProductViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()

        # appending extra data to context
        if len(self.request.FILES) > 0:
            context.update({
                'included_images': self.request.FILES
            })

        return context

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Validating images with its own serializer, but not creating.
        # The adding process must be through Serializer.
        try:
            image_serializer = ProductImageSerializer(data=request.FILES)
            image_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except Exception:
            raise NotAcceptable(
                detail={
                    'message': 'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not '
                               'an image or a corrupted image.'}, code=406)

        # the rest of method is about the product serialization(with extra context), 
        # validation and creation.
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

class ProductImageViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProductImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductImageSerializer

class TagsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tags.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagsSerializer
```

Let's examine here. As I mentioned in the comments, the image files will be included in request.FILES. For this reason, I first sent the data to the ***ProductImageSerializer*** and validated it. If a validation error occurs, the process will stop and the API will send an error message as a response. Then I sent the data to the ProductSerializer with the picture information I appended to the context in the ***get_serializer_context*** method.

We are done with the ***create*** method, other details are written on the code.

Finally, ***serializer.py***

```
from django.forms import ImageField as DjangoImageField

class TagsSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Tags
    fields = ['url', 'pk', 'name']

class ProductImageSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ['url', 'pk', 'product', 'image']
        # attention!!! if you not use this bottom line,
        # it will show error like "product required" and
        # indirectly our validation at ProductViewSet will raise error.
        extra_kwargs = {
            'product': {'required': False}
        }
    # we created Object-level custom validation because validation not working correctly.
    # when ProductImageSerializer get single image, everything just fine but
    # when it get multiple image, serializer is just passing all the files.
    def validate(self, attrs):
        default_error_messages = {
            'invalid_image':
                'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.',
        }
        # in here we're verifying image with using django.forms; Pillow not necessary !!
        for i in self.initial_data.getlist('image'):
            django_field = DjangoImageField()
            django_field.error_messages = default_error_messages
            django_field.clean(i)
        return attrs

class ProductSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer, TaggitSerializer):
    tags = TagsSerializer(allow_null=True, many=True, required=False)
    # you can delete this line. If you delete it, it will appear as url in response.
    productimage_set = ProductImageSerializer(allow_null=True, many=True, required=False)
    taggit = TagListSerializerField(allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['url', 'pk', 'name', 'tags', 'taggit', 'productimage_set']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # create product
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.create(
                name=validated_data['name']
            )
        except Exception:
            raise NotAcceptable(detail={'message': 'The request is not acceptable.'}, code=406)

        if 'included_images' in self.context:  # checking if key is in context
            images_data = self.context['included_images']
            for i in images_data.getlist('image'):
                ProductImage.objects.create(
                    product=product_obj,
                    image=i
                )

        # pop taggit and create
        if 'taggit' in validated_data:
            taggit_data = validated_data.pop('taggit')
            for taggit_data in taggit_data:
                taggit_obj, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=taggit_data)
                product_obj.taggit.add(taggit_obj)

        # pop tags and create
        if 'tags' in validated_data:
            tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
            for tags_data in tags_data:
                for i in tags_data.items():
                    tags_obj, created = Tags.objects.get_or_create(name=i[1])
                    product_obj.tags.add(tags_obj)

        return product_obj
```

So what happened here? Why did we create an extra validation for the image? Although I don't know why, ImageSerializer only makes the right validation for a single file. If you try to upload two files, you can even put a movie next to the picture, validation will not work. To prevent this, we validate the pictures in order using the built-in form of django; Change the format of .mp3 and make it .jpg, try to upload files of high size, none of them will work. The thing that makes the verification is pure django. Other details are in the code.

If you do everything as I stated, the response will be like this:

[image]

I think this will make most ***Postman*** users happy. I hope it helps. If anything catches your attention, let's meet in comments.

Comment: Hello friend, I have same kind of problem and I am stuck for 1 week now? Can you help me?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002738/having-issue-in-handling-multipart-form-data-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: hello friend, did you have a look at it?

Comment: wondering why are you putting the images in the context? `context.update({'included_images': self.request.FILES})`. Maybe because the image is lost somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If I understant it correctly, just create a ImageSerializer and attaches to the ProductSerializer. Something like that:

```
ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   #attrs 

ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productimage_set = ImageSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
```

Comment: If you try this, the image table will be empty, feel free to try it and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split image in serializer update/create method. Change your post data => productimage_set to image_set.

```
ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_set = ImageSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'color', 'image_set')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        image = validated_data.pop('image_set', None)
        # if you want you can send image another serializer here.

        instance.name = validated_data['name']
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

Comment: I used ***ForeignKey*** as I mentioned in example json data and model. Images are not included in ***validated_data*** when serializer related object `Many = True`; it only stays in request.FILES. So this method is not working.

Comment: you can define your reverse relation in product serializer. image_set= ImageSerializer(read_only=True, many=True) and change your  post data. productimage_set to image_set

Comment: hmmm this setting also was already available on my serializer. not working. If you have a method where you can add many-to-one relation related images and data using validation, can you edit your answer and share it with us?

Comment: you have one-to-many relationship for product and image models not many-to-one. if you want to use images for other products you need many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Hi @YunusEmreCevik I tried your answer. The data is shown in the `run_validation` method but after the `run_validation` method the data has no image_set in it. Can you have a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238785/django-run-validation-removing-multivaluedict-from-querydict and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192626/django-rest-multipart-data-converted-to-string